# User Defined Function with Case When Reference

Tags: r, dplyr, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to define a function that references a value in another cell according to its row (if that makes sense). Some generalized data would look like this:

```
col1  col2   col3
 A     1      B
 B     2      C
 C     6      NA
```

My goal is the below, where "calc" is a sum of col2 from the respective row and the col2 value from the referenced row

```
col1  col2  calc
 A     1      3
 B     2      8
 C     6      6

letters <- c("A","B","C")


calc<- case_when(data$col1 == "A" ~ subset(data$col2, data$col3 == "A"),
          data$col1 == "B" ~ subset(data$col2, data$col3 == "B"),
          data$col1 == "C" ~ subset(data$col2, data$col3 == "C"))
totals<- data.frame(cbind(data$col2,calc)) %>% rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE)
data.frame(cbind(data$col1,totals))
```

I'm not sure how to turn this into a function -- I tried the below,

```
udfunction<- function(x){
  calc<- case_when(data$col1 == x ~ subset(data$col2, data$col3 == x))
  totals<- data.frame(cbind(data$col1,data$col2,calc)) %>% rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE)
  data.frame(cbind(data$col1,totals))
}

udfunction(letters)
```

then got the error:

`In col1 == x : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

```
udfunction(letters)
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
transform(df, calc = col2 + c(0, col2)[match(col3, col1, 0) + 1])

  col1 col2 col3 calc
1    A    1    B    3
2    B    2    C    8
3    C    6 <NA>    6
```